# how do you build an open CV c/C++ file using Cmake exactly?

Tags: opencv, build, build-process

I have attempted to build the "kmeans.cpp" or "kmeans.c" file using gcc/g++ however I'm getting a lot of undefined references to opencv libraries, although I have installed Open CV successfully.

Can someone guide me how to build a simple C/C++ file using CMake?

Do I just do "cmake kmeans.cpp"?

I'm on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Are you using CMake GUI and which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I'm using Open CV 2.4.2 i'm not using CMake GUi, trying to stick with command line.  But if you know how to use the CMake GUI that would be helpful as well.